# SQL server DateTime and C# DateTime

Tags: c#, sql

On my SQL server I have a very simple table for testing, which only contains three rows:
`ID`, `Date` and `Hours`.(`varchar`, `DateTime`, `varchar`).

The DateTime format in SQL is like: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`.

The DateTime format in C# is like: `yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.fff`.

I use the following code to get C# DateTime format:

```
 string ddd = "2012-10-10 00:00:00.000";
 dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(ddd, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", null);
```

If I try to make it into `yyyy-dd-MM` I get an error:

> The DateTime, which is represented by the string, isn't supported by
>   the calender.

In my C# application is am trying to find total amount of hours between sunder dates. I sort of got it to working, but it only works for dates between 01 and 12.

So like from `2012-01-10` to `2012-10-10` (ten days) will give me the correct amount of total hours from the database.

But when I write `2012-01-10` to `2012-14-10` (fourteen days) I get an error:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range"

Thank you in advance.

PS. Can you suggest a easier way to get dates?

mySQL query

```
string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM date_test WHERE id = '4' AND date BETWEEN '" + dt1 + "' AND '" + dt2 + "'";
```

I have figured out the problem but not the solution.

The problem is that SQL database looks at the format, and wants yyyy-MM-dd, but C# can only send yyyy-dd-MM.

Why cannot `ParseExact()` do yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `mysql` tag? you are talking about sql server all over your question, but in the end there is a mysql query.

Comment: You are confusing the _value_ of a `DateTime` with how it is presented (formatted). The _value_ (in a `DateTime` or in a database) does not have a format as such (just an internal representation).

Comment: Use parameterised queries with parameters of correct datatypes and problem solved.

Comment: example please Martin :D

Comment: @Pavenhimself, take a look at my answer, I believe it will give you a code snippet to query the database like you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The DateTime, which is represented by the string, isn't supported by the calender.

This error is being given because your C# application views the date `2012-14-10` as saying the `14th` month, `10th` day, and `2012th year`. The day and year work find, but the month doesn't. Further, don't try and change how your C# application views the date, that's based off the culture of the system.

You're confusing how to *define* a `DateTime` object and how to *display* one.

Since you're storing your date as a `DateTime` in SQL, there's not a good reason for me to believe that you would need to do **any** kind of parsing. Consider the below code sample.

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM YourTable", "{connection string}");

dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

var yourDate = dataTable.Rows[0]["Date"]; <=== the type will be DateTime, simple.
```

### Adding Parameters

Let's take your example query:

> "SELECT * FROM date_test WHERE id = '4' AND date BETWEEN '" + dt1 + "' AND '" + dt2 + "'";

And let's fix it a bit, consider the below example:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM date_test WHERE id = @ID AND date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate", "{connection string}");

dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", "4");
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", new DateTime(2012, 10, 1));
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", new DateTime(2012, 10, 14));

dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

var yourDate = dataTable.Rows[0]["Date"]; <=== the type will be DateTime, simple.
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Finally got it to work :) All the formatting really did the job on me.

Comment: @Michael I have an issue when passing C# `DateTime` into SQL Server `SqlDBType.DateTime`. C# value = `31/07/2014 00:00:00 AM` and this returns an exception `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`. Expected sql server value format = `2014-07-31 Hh:mm:ss.fff` What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: @bonCodigo convert that string to a `DateTime` before assigning it to the parameter; like this `Convert.ToDateTime(input);`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud infact [I have done it before came to your post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25034302/1389394). And mine works - it was a just a matter of not getting the updates from the server... :)

Answer (score 4):

You're preparing a perfect ground for [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
Also look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). There's an example of parametrized query.

Comment: This program is only for my use only. No inputs from the dangerous internet :)

Comment: Then it's a great time to start forming good habits and practices. Dennis is correct; that's a perfect setup for SQL injection.

Comment: @Pavenhimself, I've got to agree with Dennis here, you should always practice just like you want to play.