# Issue when converting or casting Date String to DateTime

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, datetime

I am using jQuery DatePicker to retrieve date for a textbox in Gridview for inserting/updating records. The datepicker's date is received as a String. e.g. value "07/31/2014".

Using following code I am converting string date into a C# `DateTime`.

```
    var sDate = ((TextBox)row.FindControlRecursive("iStartDateTBox")).Text;
    payment.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "mm/dd/yyyy", null);
```

However once converted, the value set to payment's Start Date property becomes "31/01/2014 12:07:00"
I am just perplexed about what's really happening. And would like few tips to solve this.

Comment: `However once converted` ... Who did convert what into what? JavaScript string to .NET DateTime? JavaScript Date-Object to .Net string? 4 to boolean?

Comment: Why in the world the person who voted to close this question chose is as off-topic... "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center." Wonder what sort of reviewing is done in SO lately... **If this question isn't a programming question, what the sort of a question it is?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact with IFormatProvider. ( [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) )

So try something like this:

```
var result = DateTime.TryParse(
      "10. 10. 2014", 
      CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), 
      DateTimeStyles.None,
      out date);
```

Comment: +1 for answering, BUT I want more portability in my code, so don't want to specify a specific culture...

Comment: Well, then try result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 1):

It was just a matter of the [date time formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). When using `DateTime`, the code `MM` refers to month, where as `mm` refers to minutes...

THIS

```
payment.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "mm/dd/yyyy", null);
```

SHOULD BE

```
payment.StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
```