# How to get records between same date in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

When I define a "from" and "to" date to be the same value, the query is not returning any rows. When I select an extra day for the "to" date, then rows are returned.

```
string FrmDt = frmtx.Text.Trim();// 9/1/2015
string ToDt = totx.Text.Trim();//9/1/2015

select 
    rn.*,
    (select count(reue) as RequtNo 
     from tblests 
     left join aspne u on r.custorid = u.userid 
     left join aspnethip a on  u.Used=a.UserId
     where 
         u.refere = rn.refid 
         and r.Compy = 'bbb' 
         and create >= '9/1/2015'
         and create <= '9/1/2015') as refcount 
from 
    tbl_reference rn
```

Datatype: `[Createte] [datime] NOT NULL`

How to convert 9/1/2015 12:00:00 AM to 9/1/2015 11:59:59 PM ?

Comment: you can just use `createdate =  '9/1/2015'`

Comment: your date '9/1/2015' considers as 9/1/2015 00:00:00. So CreateDate may be not fall in between 9/1/2015 00:00:00 and 9/1/2015 00:00:00

Comment: Don't know if it applies to sql-server, but with MySQL I found that just specifying the date as a string defaulted to midnight, so appending the time of 23:59:59 fixed the problem - or setting the next date

Comment: i know the issue . of zero time..how to solve it @RajKamuni

Comment: Try look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563795/sql-server-datetime-and-c-sharp-datetime

Comment: @krishnamohan just append time

Comment: It's better to use international format for date : '2015-01-09' (yyyy-mm-dd) instead of '9/1/2015' because you are not tied to local settings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use it like this:

```
 createdate >=  '9/1/2015 00:00:00'and createdate <=  '9/1/2015 23:59:59'
```

or else you can switch to the next day and remove the `=` from `<=`

```
createdate >=  '9/1/2015'and createdate <  '9/2/2015'
```

To add time to your date you can try like this:

```
DateTime frmDt = new DateTime(2015, 09, 01); //time is 00:00:00 by default
DateTime toDt = new DateTime(2015, 09, 01);
TimeSpan toDtTime = TimeSpan.Parse("23:59:59");
DateTime toDtFinal = toDt.Add(ToDtTime);
```

Comment: @krishnamohan:- Whats the format of your createDate column?

Comment: [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,

Comment: can we add hours after converting date time

Comment: @krishnamohan:- Updated the answer! Please check now

Comment: cant use var..im using lower version 3.5

Comment: @krishnamohan:- Updated!

Comment: Thanks ..its worked..concatination..query have to check

Answer (score 1):

```
Convert(date,StartTime) >= '2022-09-1' and Convert(date,EndTime) <= '2022-12-02'
```

It woked for me when I converted it to date from datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `createdate` field is a datetime and you define your date stating the date only, the time defaults to 00:00:01. You have three options to deal with that:

1. Set the range to 9/1/2015 - 9/2/2015, which would select whole 24
   hours of 9/1/2015
2. Set the time explicitly to like 00:00:01 and 23:59:59 respectively like 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html for examples).
3. Do not define a range at all. Simply search for entries from a specific day like this:

   ...WHERE DATE(createdate) = '2015-09-01' ...

**BTW:** in MySQL you define dates as YYYY-MM-DD, so your '9/1/2015' should be '2015-09-01' in fact.

Comment: i want to see the records between dates and between one day @hubert

Comment: i cant use mysql,,,sorry

Comment: how to convert 9/1/2015 12:00:00 AM to 
9/1/2015 11:59:59 PM

Comment: regarding your exact code (frmtx and totx) you might want to check whether they're defined as date or datetime. It should be the first if you go with solution 1 and the latter if you go for solution 2.

Comment: In YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format your datetime would be 2015-09-01 23:59:59. Note the different date notation and the european time notation (no AM or PM).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this way:

declare @tempDate datetime = '2015-09-01'
declare @endDate datetime = DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @tempDate))

Here @tempDate os your current date. Now how @endDate is calculated, just add 1 day to @tempDate, then subtract 1 second from that, so you will get the today's date with max time. Now you can simply write query to get date between these two dates.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. Replace the hard coded date to the date column

```
string FrmDt = frmtx.Text.Trim();// 9/1/2015
string ToDt = totx.Text.Trim();//9/1/2015

select 
    rn.*,
    (select count(reue) as RequtNo 
     from tblests 
     left join aspne u on r.custorid = u.userid 
     left join aspnethip a on  u.Used=a.UserId
     where 
         u.refere = rn.refid 
         and r.Compy = 'bbb' 
        AND (YEAR('9/1/2015')=2015 AND MONTH('9/1/2015')= 9 AND DAY('9/1/2015')=1)
         --and create >= '9/1/2015'
         --and create <= '9/1/2015') as refcount 
from 
    tbl_reference rn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to change the query like me, I added this in C# in code behind,

```
DateTime from =Convert.ToDateTime(_dataRange[0]);
            DateTime to =Convert.ToDateTime(_dataRange[1]);

            if (from == to)
            {
                to = to.AddHours(23.99); //this gives me 11:59PM in same date
            }
```