# Convert string dd/mm/yyy to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a string

```
string str = "26/01/2015";
```

I need to convert it into datetime as `2015-01-26 00:00:00.000` so that I can store it in database.

What I have tried so far is

```
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`
```

and I am getting the value as `'26/01/2015 12:00:00 AM'`.

But I need it as  `2015-01-26 00:00:00.000`.

Is it possible? Any help appreciated

Comment: Note that your post is [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - while exact question is answered there is no real value for you in the answers....

Comment: So @AlexeiLevenkov which post do you suggest me?

Comment: Sounds like searching for https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+store+datetime+sql should give good examples like - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563795/sql-server-datetime-and-c-sharp-datetime. Unfortunately I don't think there is canonical answer about value of `DateTime` and how it is displayed in debugger/`ToString`/other text representations which may be what you actually have problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert it to string like this (if you want it as formatted string):

```
var parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var formatted = parsed.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

I presume you want to have formatted datetime string.

Comment: Its working fine. But we are parsing as a string for a datetime field. Is it the proper way?

Comment: @ShreyasBhandimatt Are you using ORM to store data in database? If you do, you can store your datetime as is. So you don't need to make it a formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

once you have the DateTime object you could just update your database because it's the most accurate one. What matter to you on the output is when you retrieve it back from database, it is datetime object then do your .ToString to format it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string outputFormat = DateTime.ParseExact("26/01/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

But I think it is better to keep this as a DateTime to write it to the database, not string

Answer (score 0):

You convert it to string and pass the parameters to ToString() function as described in [these standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) as per your need.

You can use

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
d.ToString("U");
```

Comment: Why `U` specifier? This _may_ generate different results for different cultures.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to worry about converting a datetime if you use a parameter to store the data like the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connStr = "Enter Your Conneciton String Here";
            string SQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 (Time_Col) VALUES ('@MyTime');";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now();
            cmd.Parameters["@MyTime"].Value = now;

            cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}
```