# Mismatches on DateTime between C# and SQL server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I create DateTime in C# like this

`DateTime oDate = Convert.ToDateTime(xate);`

that returns `22/09/2020 01:27:00 ب.ظ}`

and save it in SQL server after saving I see the time that stored is Weird
like this

[image]

and when I try to run a SQL command like this

```
INSERT INTO HomeVisit (LifeplusCaseId, FromDateTime, ToDateTime)
VALUES ('39909F03-2DEF-4682-89CA-0000DCC3E098','22/09/2020 12:00:00 ق.ظ', '22/09/2020 12:00:00 ق.ظ');
```

I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I figure out the time that generates in C# is vice versa the format in the SQL Server.

I don't know how to save DateTime in C# to SQL Server.

My code for saving datatime in SQL Server is:

```
HomeVisitRow homeVisit = BehzistiDb2.List<HomeVisitRow>().Where(x => x.LifeplusCaseId == lifeplusCaseId && x.FromDateTime <= oDate && x.ToDateTime > oDate).FirstOrDefault();

if (homeVisit == null)
{
    homeVisit = new HomeVisitRow
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        LifeplusCaseId = lifeplusCaseId,
        FromDateTime = oDate,
        ToDateTime = oDate.AddMonths(6) 
    };

    BehzistiDb2.Insert<HomeVisitRow>(homeVisit);
```

Comment: Hi i think you have bad compatibility with "culture" C# and "collation" SQL Server . 
Please add some information about your SQL server collation and your culture C#

Comment: Can you show us your c# code that save the datetime into SQL Server ?

Comment: Concerning the second part of your question: are you sure that `ق.ظ` is an appropriate value for the field `ToDateTime`?

Comment: Hi think this post can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563795/sql-server-datetime-and-c-sharp-datetime

Comment: There's some weird unicode RTL flipping going on in your sql sample, but it looks like you're missing `', '` between your two date strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string

The problem is that you insert a string `' '` into your SQL Database instead of a DateTime Object like you specified.

We can create a DateTime Object from a string easily if we use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`

**Example:**

```cs
DateTime fromDate;
string txtStartDate = "22/09/2020 01:27:00";
DateTime.TryParseExact(txtStartDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out fromDate);

Console.WriteLine(fromDate.ToString());
```

Now we can also insert that Variable into our SQL Statement as it's value.

```
INTO HomeVisit (LifeplusCaseId, FromDateTime, ToDateTime)
VALUES ('39909F03-2DEF-4682-89CA-0000DCC3E098', fromDate, toDate);
```

Comment: it's correct ,it was related to culture but I didn't get these line of code ```System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, ```

Answer (score 0):

You format the date according to your requirement just see the below examples.

```
DateTime oDate = Convert.ToDateTime(xate); 
oDate = oDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: your example returns a string but I need date-time as result!

Comment: and I convert it this way`` oDate = DateTime.Parse(oDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));`` but dosent work